# In JBoss, how do I make my war start after my sar?

Tags: jboss, war, sar

Within my service I have an mbean which is accessed by my war file. How do I ensure that the war file is deployed and started after the service?

Comment: Are these all part of an EAR, or deployed individually?

Comment: Currently these are deployed individually but I can change how I deploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the service is deployed as a sar, then you don't have to do anything. sar's are deployed before war's.

Comment: You're right - I had tried this but because of a silly bug elsewhere it looked like it wasn't working. Thanks.